# iPhone WiFi connection withou access point

Tags: iphone, wifi, access-point

I'm working on a project in which I want to wirelessly connect two simplistic devices to an iPhone, however, I will not have a cellular connection and I do not want to use an access point. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: any news? have you tried what I suggested you?

Answer (score 0):

iPhone has a "Personal Hotspot" feature (you can turn it on in Settings) which transforms the phone into a wifi access point. so you can then let other devices connect to it.

Comment: I have Verizon which charges an arm and a leg for this feature. I can buy an inexpensive access point for $40 or pay $20 to Verizon....